# angular 6 scroll top not working in mat angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular6

```
public expenseClicked(cat_id: any, label: any,e) {
window.scrollTo(0, 0);
console.log(e);
//this.expense_chart_data('YES', cat_id, label);
if (this.clickbtn_status === 1) {
    this.backbtn_status = 'A';
    this.click_count = this.click_count + 1;
    // this.chartLevel = this.chartLevel + 1;
    //console.log('chartClicked inside ====' + cat_id);
    this.expense_chart_data('YES', cat_id, label);
}
this.expense_chart_data('YES', cat_id, label);
```

}

{{chartlist.name}}
                                        {{chartlist.value | currency:'INR'}}
                                    
                                    
                                        arrow_forward_ios

Answer (score 0):

Use **ViewportScroller**

Inject ViewportScroller in constructor and It provide method called scrollToPosition

**Try this**

**component.html**

```
constructor(private viewportScroller: ViewportScroller) {}
```

**component.ts**

```
public expenseClicked(cat_id: any, label: any,e) {
this.viewportScroller.scrollToPosition([0, 0]);
console.log(e);
//this.expense_chart_data('YES', cat_id, label);
if (this.clickbtn_status === 1) {
    this.backbtn_status = 'A';
    this.click_count = this.click_count + 1;
    // this.chartLevel = this.chartLevel + 1;
    //console.log('chartClicked inside ====' + cat_id);
    this.expense_chart_data('YES', cat_id, label);
}
```